# React hook how to change property of array object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to change **boolean** property of every object using React useState hook?

```
const [showCard, setShowCard] = useState([
    { id: 1, show: true }, 
    { id: 2, show: true }
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function to `setShowCard` – see the [*Functional updates* section in the documentation of `useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). The first argument is the previous state, which you can map over to e.g. toggle the `show` property of every item:

```js
setShowCard(prevState => prevState.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  show: !item.show,
})));
```

Runnable example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [showCard, setShowCard] = useState([
    { id: 1, show: true }, 
    { id: 2, show: true },
  ]);

  function toggle() {
    setShowCard(prevState => prevState.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      show: !item.show,
    })))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(showCard, null, 2)}</pre>
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```